# Modal not updating data on row 2 and so on

Tags: php, bootstrap-modal

Hi so the modal works fine on the first row but when i clicked on the 2nd row modal doesnt fetch any data

The form where it fetches the data , this thing works on first page only or either no

```
 $ID = $_POST['ID'];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `unity_users` WHERE `uid` = '$ID'";
$res = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
if(mysqli_num_rows($res)>0){
  $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res);
$htmlToReturn = '<form action="" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="formTopMargin" autocomplete="off" method="post">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="cat">User Name:</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" value="'.$row['name'].'" name = "name">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="cat">Email:</label>
          <input type="email" class="form-control" value="'.$row['email'].'" name = "email">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="cat">Score:</label>
          <input type="number" class="form-control" value="'.$row['score'].'" name = "score">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="cat">PPA:</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" value="'.$row['ppa'].'" name = "ppa">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="cat">Hash:</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" value="'.$row['hash'].'" name = "hash">
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="hidden" hidden value="'.$row['uid'].'" name = "uid">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3"></div>
  </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-3"></div>
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <button type="submit" name="update" class="btn loginButton">Update</button>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-3"></div>
    </div>
  </form>';
```

The Output of the code

```
    <?php
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM `unity_users`";
        $res = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
        if(mysqli_num_rows($res)>0){
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)) {
              echo '<tr>';
                echo '<td>'.$row['uid'].'</td>';
                echo '<td>'.$row['name'].'</td>';
                echo '<td>'.$row['email'].'</td>';
                echo '<td>'.$row['score'].'</td>';
                echo '<td>'.$row['ppa'].'</td>';
                echo '<td>'.$row['hash'].'</td>';
                if($row['payment']=="Released"){
                  $payment = "requested";
                }else{
                  $payment = "pending";
                }
                echo '<td>'.$payment.'</td>';
                echo '<td class="pointer"><i id="delete_'.$row['uid'].'" class="fa fa-trash fa-2x details" aria-hidden="true"></i></td>';              
                echo '<td class="pointer"><i data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" id="edit_'.$row['uid'].'" class="fa fa-pencil-square-o fa-2x details" aria-hidden="true"></i></td>';
              echo '</tr>';
            }
          }
     ?>
```

The modal

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
<div class="modal-dialog">
  <div class="modal-content">
     <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 style="text-align:  center;margin-top:  1%;font-size: 25px;" class="modal-title">User Data</h4>
      </div>
    <div class="modal-body" id="categoryModel">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[First row which is working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R270w.png)

[Updating data is working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iuxea.png)

[Page 2 second row not working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ump9R.png)

Comment: the php code that you have shown us may not have anything to do with the error. After all the modal is triggered by Javascript, and it really depends on how your front end application interact with the backend, then we will be able to assess the problem.

Comment: Please edit your question ... linking 1, 2 and 3 with images without description is really ugly.

Comment: I just edited the code I hope you can now undestand what my problem is or is there anyway to show all data in 1 table if the code is working on 1 table only what if I will show all data in 1 row just like it loops?